# Custom drug names vocabulary for SpeechRecogniser in Android

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I have an app in which I want users to filter drugs using voice recognition, As some of you may know drug names are not always in proper English and therefore not recognisable by google's voiceRecogniser.

I want to ask if there is a way to train the recogniser to only recognize drug names for example providing an array of expected results.
If there are ways using machine learning I'd like to know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can train many other external recognizers - kaldi, cmusphinx, google cloud speech api (paid), ibm speech api (paid), microsoft and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your comment I actually started using cmusphinx if you'd like you can post it as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: @shahawi273, Did you succeed in adding custom words in cmusphinx? 
I had studied various options for adding custom words in various speech to text engines. Google was simplest to use, but there is no way to add custom words. Microsoft was ok and I successfully added few custom words, but was cost heavy (calculation was not fitting my business model). Rest I could not find a simple way.

Comment: Hi,


Sadly this was a trivial project that I did not pursue further.


However, I remember my problem was that I needed to record thousands of words and to write down each custom word which would have taken months to complete.